# multiple applications single config file

Tags: service, .net-4.0, app-config

I'm trying to write a service and configuration application. VB/C++ 2010 I've had a number of hits on google but they largely seem to be obsolete. What I have so far is a project with a single form app and a service app. The single form app has an "app.config" file and I have added a section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="settings.config">
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In the Solution I have added a "settings.config" file and its contents is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="This is Setting 1 from settings.config" />
    <add key="Setting2" value="This is Setting 2 from settings.config" />
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="ConnectString from settings.confg" />
</appSettings>
```

I have added a reference to then C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Configuration.dll

library in both the forms app and the service app

In the very simple forms app i have the following code

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim s As String = _
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString")
        TextBox1.Text = s
    End Sub
```

It doesn't work! Now clearly I am missing something. Its probably very simple. But my limited understanding is that this is automatically configuered by the config files I have? MS in their usual helful fashion seem to only give samples for 2012 and net 4.5 or greater. I need this to work on a 2003 server (as well) so I'm limited to net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the line `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString")` is looking for the key `ConnectionString` in your application's `app.config` file.

The fact that you have included that `file` key in your app.config file doesn't magically tell the `ConfigurationManager` to load the settings from a different file. If that's what you want you will have to read the setting for the `file` key and then manually load the configuration from that file.

This has not changed since the early versions of .Net though so I'm not sure why you were conflicted by the examples.

Comment: Miky, put it down to head in other things, being rusty and not seeing the wood for the trees. I'm going that way now, just getting the syntax

Comment: Ok, the way to go (after much messing about) is a separate config file with a custom section and class which is in the windows application data folder. The folder is termined by the company name and app name and accessed from a common dll with a file watcher to provide auto update

Answer (score 0):

Add reference on existing assembly in `.Net section` of your `Add Reference Popup`

But i suggest you to use `connectionStrings section` in your config file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>

string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```